# What's wrong with this audio stream playing code for Android?

Tags: android, streaming, media-player

I have a problem with this code for live streaming:

```
package cm.ex.wwd;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class AudioStream extends Activity {

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  String url = "http://www.songblasts.com/songs/hindi/t/three-idiots/01-Aal_Izz_Well-(SongsBlasts.Com).mp3";
  MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
  try {
   mp.setDataSource(url);
   mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
   mp.prepare();
   mp.start();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   Log.i("Exception", "Exception in streaming mediaplayer e = " + e);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Hay check this link will solve it http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/

Comment: hey please first check your url its not working..

Answer (score 1):

url you are giving is not a valid one.it is showing 404 NOT FOUND.so it is creating problem for you.give a valid one

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact problem it is difficult to answer. If you do this on your UI Thread you might also run into an application crash as the call to `prepare()` might take to long. Better use [`prepareAsync()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#prepareAsync%28%29) and the associated listeners when using streaming.

As mentioned before, also the URL gives a 404.

Answer (score 0):

i have done little changes in above code. check out this one.

```
player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        player.setDataSource("http://www.hubharp.com/web_sound/BachGavotte.mp3");
        player.setOnErrorListener(this);
        player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        player.prepareAsync();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    player.release();
    player = null;
}
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer play) {
    play.start();
}
@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    return false;
}
```